# Go to another page when finish processing form

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a form, that when I press the submit button, I process the data as I want. What I want is to go to another page, or the previous page. What my page is, at first a list of links, when I press on a link, another page opens with questions to answer, after I answer them, I need to go back to the choosing page. I tried `header()` as this was what most people said to use, but I stay on the same page, I tried the using the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0" url="the page to go to">` but this seems to refresh the same page over and over again. How can I make it that when I press submit, and process the questions, to go back to the choosing page.

Thanks

NOTE: If code is needed, please tell me so that I post them.

EDIT:

Here is the code where I tried using the `header()` and `http_redirect()`

```
<?php

// topic 1

try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mawarid;host=localhost", "khaled", "");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $q_qry = "select * from question where question_topic='1';";
    $questions = $db->query($q_qry)->fetchAll();

} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // code here for handling error
    print "error";
    print "\n".$ex->getMessage()."\n";
}

?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <html>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>topic 1</title>
    </html>

    <body>

        <h1>topic 1:</h1>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <ol>
<?php
                foreach ($questions as $question) {

                    $qa_qry = "select * from answer where question='$question[0]';";
                    $ans = $db->query($qa_qry)->fetchAll();             
?>

                    <li><?= $question[1] ?></li>

<?php
                    foreach ($ans as $a) {
                        $radio_name = "q".$question[0];
?>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="<?= $radio_name ?>" value="<?= $a[0] ?>"><?= $a[1] ?></label><br/>
<?php
                    }
                }
?>
            </ol>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>

<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $user_ans = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $ans_access = "q".$i;
        $user_ans[$i] = $_POST[$ans_access];
    }

//  $correct = $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["correct"];
//  $wrong = $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["wrong"];

    $correct = 0;
    $wrong = 0;

    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        if ($question[2] == $user_ans[$question[0]])
            $correct++;
        else
            $wrong++;
    }

    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_score_correct"][0] = $correct;
    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_score_wrong"][0] = $wrong;

    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_done"][0] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["correct"] += $correct;
    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["wrong"] += $wrong;

    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["last_topic_id"] = 1;

    // header("Location:choosetopic.php");
    http_redirect("choosetopic.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Code is usually the best place to start. It's hard to `operate` without a `patient` on the table. ;-)

Comment: How do you evaluate wihich page do you want to go to?

Comment: Just curious but are there any specific error reports you could please provide us with. Also I assume when you were told to use the header() call they said you cannot have any displayed data code above the redirect? In context of your main code I cannot see this; but make sure you don't have any HTML or echos before the header() call.

Comment: `@OP`: I for one am also curious. What is the `name(php)` of the page that your code is in? Wouldn't be `choosetopic.php` by any chance?

Comment: Ohh, the page name this code is from is `topic1.php`, and `choosetopic.php` is where I have links to 9 topics to choose from, so what I'm trying to do is after I finish from the first topic and submit it, I want to go back to the page where I choose another topic

Comment: Sorry, I can't wrap my head around this one. You guys have a go at it. The only thing I can think of is, to get rid of your header redirection and replace it with an `echo "<a href='choosetopic.php'>Choose another topic</a>";` type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated you processed the data on the current page you do not need to pass the data from one page to another. Therefore as soon as you are finished processing the data you can just move to another page. So just add the appropriate header right under the code where you processed the data.

```
header('Location:otherpage.php');
```

With your newly posted code I noticed you have HTML above your header() call. This is not allowed in order to prevent developers from inefficiently proccessing unecessary code. (AKA why display data if you are going to be instantly redirected before you can see it)

Try adding the processing code and header() call to the top of your page like this:

```
<?php

// topic 1

try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mawarid;host=localhost", "khaled", "");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $q_qry = "select * from question where question_topic='1';";
    $questions = $db->query($q_qry)->fetchAll();

} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // code here for handling error
    print "error";
    print "\n".$ex->getMessage()."\n";
}



session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $user_ans = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $ans_access = "q".$i;
        $user_ans[$i] = $_POST[$ans_access];
    }

//  $correct = $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["correct"];
//  $wrong = $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["wrong"];

    $correct = 0;
    $wrong = 0;

    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        if ($question[2] == $user_ans[$question[0]])
            $correct++;
        else
            $wrong++;
    }

    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_score_correct"][0] = $correct;
    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_score_wrong"][0] = $wrong;

    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_done"][0] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["correct"] += $correct;
    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["wrong"] += $wrong;

    $_SESSION["contestant_name"]["last_topic_id"] = 1;

    // header("Location:choosetopic.php");
    http_redirect("choosetopic.php");
}


?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <html>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>topic 1</title>
    </html>

    <body>

        <h1>topic 1:</h1>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <ol>
<?php
                foreach ($questions as $question) {

                    $qa_qry = "select * from answer where question='$question[0]';";
                    $ans = $db->query($qa_qry)->fetchAll();             
?>

                    <li><?= $question[1] ?></li>

<?php
                    foreach ($ans as $a) {
                        $radio_name = "q".$question[0];
?>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="<?= $radio_name ?>" value="<?= $a[0] ?>"><?= $a[1] ?></label><br/>
<?php
                    }
                }
?>
            </ol>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't be presumptuous, and I quote the OP `I tried header() as this was what most people said to use, but I stay on the same page...`.

Comment: Yeah, well maybe he added it to the wrong place. You cannot have any displayed data above the header call; which is why I specifically said to add it right under the data processing (assuming he doesn't have any output above that).

Comment: We can't know for sure, since there's nothing (code) for us to bite on. You may very well be right ;-)

Comment: @aizen92 Thanks for adding your relevant source code; is there any other code above the provided PHP code in your file?

Comment: Ohh yeh, I didn't notice I posted half of the page, sorry about that.
I posted the whole code

Comment: @aizen92 I noticed you have HTML above your header() call. Please add the session_start(); and if(isset($_POST["submit"])) code to the very top of your php page. You cannot have displayed data code above the call.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: http:your link")
```

should do the trick. Make sure there's no echo in your page before that line, however.

Answer (score -1):

use the action attribute

```
<form method="post" action="other-page.php"> 
...
```

Comment: I think the point is that the form handler and the page he wants visitors to land on after processing the form submission are not the same page.

Comment: I am not sure why this got -1. But just a note with this solution it is required to take all data processing code from the first page and place it on the newly directed page.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but from what I can tell by the updated code, the OP wants his entire code to be run in the same place, thus having the empty form action set as a `self`.

Answer (score -1):

Once you've finished processing the data, you can issue a `http_redirect()`; this does the same thing as `header('Location:...')` but might be a little easier to use. See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

Comment: @aizen92 How about showing us some code? I for one, never showed up in `mind reading classes`, and my superpowers have been drained from last night; TMI.